# How to change default browser of cordova browser platform?

Tags: cordova

I don't have chrome installed and I mainly use other browsers for development (opera, yandex etc). But the command:

> cordova run browser

uses chrome by default, so it fails with " The system can not find the file chrome.". Can I change which browser cordova uses?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way to change the default Chrome browser is using the [`--target` option](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#cordova-run-command).

As you can see [Chrome is the default browser for the `run` command](https://github.com/apache/cordova-browser/blob/master/bin/templates/project/cordova/run#L40).

Internally, the [cordovaServe.launchBrowser function](https://github.com/apache/cordova-browser/blob/master/bin/templates/project/cordova/run#L51) is called with cli arguments.

This function [is defined in the cordova-serve/serve.js file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-browser/blob/master/node_modules/cordova-serve/serve.js#L53) and you can find its body in the [cordova-serve/src/browser.js file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-browser/blob/master/node_modules/cordova-serve/src/browser.js#L32) where you can find the complete list of supported browsers for each platform:

```
var browsers = {
    'win32': {
        'ie': 'iexplore',
        'chrome': 'chrome --user-data-dir=%TEMP%\\' + dataDir,
        'safari': 'safari',
        'opera': 'opera',
        'firefox': 'firefox',
        'edge': 'microsoft-edge'
    },
    'darwin': {
        'chrome': '"Google Chrome" --args' + chromeArgs,
        'safari': 'safari',
        'firefox': 'firefox',
        'opera': 'opera'
    },
    'linux' : {
        'chrome': 'google-chrome' + chromeArgs ,
        'chromium': 'chromium-browser' + chromeArgs,
        'firefox': 'firefox',
        'opera': 'opera'
    }
};
```

I hope that this answer will help you to learn a bit more about cordova and the way it works.

Comment: any bad with adding yandex to the list?

Comment: You could create, inside your execution path, a symlink called "chrome" that points to the "yandex" bin. Otherwise you should open an issue in the cordova tracker.

Answer (score 23):

Test the following command:

> cordova run browser --target=firefox

Answer (score 0):

```
ionic cordova run browser -lc --target=chrome
```